# How do i translate movement on the Canvas3D to movement in the virtual 3D world

Tags: virtual, translation, java-3d, canvas3d

My goal is to move a shape in the virtual world in such a way so that it ends up where the mouse pointer is on the canvas.

What i have:
-mouse position (x,y) on a Canvas3D object
-Point3d object of where a pick ray starting from the Canvas3D viewport intersects with the first scene object. (point in 3D space of where i want to start the drag)

What i want:
-Some way to translate the Point3d's coordinates so that the initial point of intersection (the Point3d object) is always overlapping the the mouse position on the canvas (same as when i used the pick ray to determine what the user clicked on from the Canvas3D object).

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to specify the behaviour of the movement in 3D i.e. how the 2D mouse movement corresponds to a 3D movement eg. you could define some sort of plane in 3D that the object is to move along. Did you have any ideas on that or is that what you are really asking about?

Comment: right now i have a background cube (0 depth along the z axis) and i have shapes in front of it.  I want to move the shape or distort the mesh based on where the user clicks and where the intersection point is with the shape.  This code is all fine.  What i want to do though is see the shape move or distort to where the mouse is on the canvas as i drag the mouse.  Right now the shape is lagging behind the mouse by a lot, say 3x the mouse distance on the canvas.  Right now i'm also doing the distortion based on where the mouse intersects with the background image ...

Comment: which has another drawback of me not being able to drag the shape to a point past the background (my background does not take up the entire virtual world, this is intentional).

Comment: So to answer your question, i don't want any object in 3D space that is visible, but if i can define the plane logically, then yes that is what i want.  I want the shape to move along the plane of the viewport sometimes, or the plane of the background most other times.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've added a brief answer. If you need more detail then just say.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you want to use the plane which is parallel to the background plane and contains the intersection point with the object. You can use this plane even when the mouse moves beyond the actual background as it's just a mathematical concept which stretches to infinity.

I'm not a Java programmer so I can't give you code but I am a mathematician so here's equation you need ;)

Let P denote the original intersection point and call the background plane unit normal n. This normal is also the normal of our plane of interest. Let R denote a point on the ray and l denote it's unit direction vector.

Then the equation of the plane is (x-P).n = 0 for a point x in the plane (the . denotes dot product of two vectors). The equation of a point on the ray is x = R + t*l where t is any real number. The ray therefore intersects the plane when

(t*l + R - P).n = 0

i.e. when

t = (P - R).n / ( l.n )

This gives you a t value to plug back into your ray equation to give the intersection point.

Comment: Ok, but can you provide me some code given that i know the intersection point with the shape (Point3d intersectionWithShape) and the start and end x,y position on the canvas3D, call them Point start and Point end?  Also I have the plane of the background, right now it's along the x-y plane and it's at z=0, but it could move in the future.

Comment: Do you have the means to calculate the 3D ray from your 2D co-ordinate?

Comment: If you mean the pick ray from the canvas then yes.  That is how i obtained the intersection point with the shape in my scene.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I've added the relevant maths for you. It should easy to implement in Java I would think.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try to implement that in Java, though I can't right now.  Also, I'm not sure if i will be able to given that the pick ray, intersection code is handled for me through the Java3D API, so if anyone knows how to use Java3D method to do this that would be great.  In the mean time, as soon as i get a chance i will try to do it with the math you provided above, I hope it will work :).  Thanks a lot!